# What's a cross-platform solution for tagging files on a USB drive?

Tags: search, tags, cross-platform

I'd like to add custom search tags for Spotlight, Windows Search, and Linux Beagle, all on the same NTFS-formatted USB drive. What's the closest software solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Also there is [Tagspaces](http://www.tagspaces.org) but it modifies the file names according to the tags (e.g. `Flower.jpg` becomes `Flower[flower image private fresh].jpg`) which may or may not be a good thing. If you want to handle files/directories without modifying it directly (for people who do not use Tagspaces) - that won't be possible with this approach.

Comment: @Flimm Are you sure about the spaces like `[x y]` between the tags? I thought it would be separate brackets like `[x][y]`...

Comment: I just tried it now and it did spaces.

Answer (score 0):

[Elyse](http://silkwoodsoftware.com/) works in Mac and Windows, but not Linux. Unknown whether it can store the tag database on the USB drive, or if it must store the database on the main internal hard drive.